# delete subdirectories only at maxdepth 2 and above

Tags: linux, find

I have directory with 6 subdirectories but I wish to delete subdirectories from only 3 of them, hence I used a for loop to 'cd' inside these 3 directories, but I want to delete the subdirectories at depth 2 (maxdepth, mindepth as 2) inside the 3 subdirectories.
I was using a find command at base(base is one of the 3 sub-directories) but it will find the directories from depth 1 (which is expected)

my file structure is
`/a/b/c/d/e`
(a is one of the 3 directories I'm iterating over)

a part of he code is below where I would need help/guidance -
`find /a -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -mtime +30`

this will output -
`./b/c`

So I do **not** wish to delete the directory `/b` and delete only directory `c` and below/inside depths

Is there a way to do this or I will HAVE to cd to the `b` directory?

Comment: I this a question on how `-delete` or `rm` operate? `rm` (or `-delete`) on `a/b/c` will only delete `c` and leave `a/b` untouched. It must however be a result of your search, als `find` will show the path. `b` would only be deleted, if the results showed `./b` or `a/b` (i.e. `b` as the main result of the search).

Comment: `find /a ...` ..   " this will output - `./b/c`" -- no, it won't, it'll output `/a/b/c`, etc. Besides, you might as well create some directory structure and test `find ... -delete` on it to see what actually gets deleted. `mkdir -p /a/b/c/d` could help.

Comment: @ilkkachu you are correct `find /a ` will output the absolute path i.e. `/a/b/c`  (considering i'm at ~), I had the output `./b/c` because i was already in the directory `/a` and I had provided the command `find . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -mtime +30`

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the command to execute a `rm -rf` on the found directories, but you should be *extremely careful* as it can lead to data loss. Here's how to do it:

```bash
find /a -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -mtime +30 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

As always, you should test the command with an `echo` first:

```bash
find /a -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -mtime +30 -exec echo "Deleting: {}" \;
```

This will print the directories it would delete, allowing you to verify the command's behavior before actually deleting anything.

**EDIT:** Is it something like this you're looking for?
The command below is not destructive.

```bash
find /a -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -mtime +30 -exec sh -c 'cd "{}" && echo "Deleting contents of $(pwd)"' \;
```

This command **IS DESTRUCTIVE!**

```bash
find /a -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -mtime +30 -exec sh -c 'cd "{}" && rm -rf *' \;
```

Comment: My main concern is the part where I mention I do **not** wish the delete the `b` directory at depth 1 - which is included in the output of my `find` command

Comment: @user16454406 Please see my edit.

Comment: I think that last command will delete the contents of `./b/c` but not the directory `./b/c` itself which is what is being asked for. If `{}` is `./b/c` then your original version (`sh -c 'rm -r {}'`) will delete `./b/c` but not `./b` alone. That was already correct. The edit isn't necessary.

Comment: @user16454406 The `b` directory shouldn't appear in the output of your find command (without a subdirectory appearing as well) because it would be excluded by `-mindepth 2`. It's at mindepth 1.

Comment: Also embedding `{}`  in the code argument of  `sh` is very  bad practice. It introduces command injection vulnerabilities

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm the current author of rawhide (rh) (see https://github.com/raforg/rawhide)

Hi, With rawhide (rh) you can do:

```
rh -m2 -M2 -x 'rm -r %s' /a 'd && old(30*days)'
```

To check first:

```
rh -m2 -M2 -x 'echo rm -r %s' /a 'd && old(30*days)'
```

`-m2` is the same as `-mindepth 2`.

`-M2` is the same as `-maxdepth 2`.

`-x ...` executes the given shell command on each match.

`%s` is replaced by the matching filepath (like find's `{}`).

`/a` is a search path.

`'d && old(30*days)'` matches directories (`d`) that haven't been modified (entries added or deleted) in at least 30 days (`old(30*days)` or `old(month)`).

Note: Checking the `mtime` of a directory only considers each directory's own `mtime`, not the `mtime` of any of its contents. The same is true with `find`.

Comment: the `mtime` of a directory does get modified if its contents are modified, tested on my amazon linux machine

Comment: @user16454406, the mtime of a directory is only modified when an entry is added, removed  or renamed in that directory (not  in  subdirectories). If you modify a file within that directory without  changing its name (and without a `.swp` or backup copy of the original being added as some text editors do), then the mtime of the directory is not modified.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the useful inputs, I was able to replicate my question/issue on my personal machine.

I was able to achieve solution to my issue with below command -
*somecode...*
`base2=$(pwd)` i.e. `/a`
`find $base2 -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -mtime +30 | xargs rm -R`
this will output `/a/b/c` however as specified it will remove only the directory at depth 2  i.e. `/c`
After the command run we are left with `/a/b` so works as per my requirement.

Comment: `pwd` is the command that prints the value of the `$PWD` variable. `$(pwd)` mangles it as it removes the trailing newline characters.  `$base2` mangles it even more as you forgot to quote it (unless you use a saner shell like zsh) and piping to `xargs` without using `-print0`/`-0` does even more mangling as `xargs`'s expected input format doesn't match the default output format of `find`. Should be `find "$PWD" -mindepth  2  -maxdepth 2 -type d -mtime +30 -exec rm -rf {} +`.

Comment: In any case using thé full path of `.` instead of `.` is rather pointless and will only make it less efficient and less reliable.